# Buttons press in specific order in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I want to create an UIViewController with for buttons. I want the user to press that four buttons with specific order. What I have done until now is that i give a random tag number in every button with the following code:

```
-(void)prepareArray {
self.arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
while (self.arary.count <4) {
    int value = arc4random()%4;
    BOOL isFound = [[self.arary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
    if(!isFound)
        [self.arary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", arary);
button1.tag = [[arary objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
button2.tag = [[arary objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
button3.tag = [[arary objectAtIndex:2]intValue];
button4.tag = [[arary objectAtIndex:3]intValue];
```

So my question is: how can I create a method in which I got an order of pressing the buttons from 0 to 3? I tried with case and with if statements and I can not figure this out?

Comment: you have to set integer value in every button then you can find the order of sequence.. show me button code so that i can answer you

Comment: The code that i have posted is the code that sets the integer value to every button. Every time that controller starts the integer assign changes. Thats why i want to track let say the correct order of pressing the buttons which will be 0,1,2,3.

Comment: so you are feeling difficulty in putting condition for getting button sequence?

Comment: yes exactly. I can not figure it out.

Comment: **I read your question and code many times, sorry to say, but I'm not getting what you're trying to say.**

Comment: What I am trying to do is. When the user presses a button I add it´s tag to a NSMutableArray. So when all the buttons pressed I want to check if the order is 1,2,3,4 then ok else not ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button{

[clickDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",button.tag] forKey:button.titleLabel.text];
NSLog(@"clickDictionary : %@", clickDictionary);
```

}

You can write method as above. This method will be called on every button click.
In clickDictionary you will get the button name and its tag.
You can sort this dictionary as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with the following method. Firstly I create my buttons with a for loop:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
    self.theButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    self.theButtons = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, y, 100, 40)];
    [self.theButtons setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Press Me"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theButtons setTag:[[data.randomArray objectAtIndex:count]intValue]];
    [self.theButtons addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.theButtons setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.buttonArray addObject:theButtons];
    [self.view addSubview:theButtons];
    y=y+60;
}
```

and attach the tag for the buttons with:

```
self.randomArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
while (self.randomArray.count <4) {
    int value = arc4random()%4+1;
    BOOL isFound = [[self.randomArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
    if(!isFound)
        [self.randomArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
}
```

Finally if i want to check in which order the user pushed the buttons I create another array:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
    {
        NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked.", (long int)[button tag]);
        int value = [button tag];
        button.hidden = YES;
        [buttonArray removeObject:button];
        //When user taps a button another array created which stores the button tags
        if([addIntArray indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]] == NSNotFound) {
            [addIntArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
    }
```

and compare it´s button click with a static array.